# sfWidgetFormJQueryDate doesn't pass validation in Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to add sfWidgetFormJQueryDate to my project, but it doesn't want to pass validation, it shows *"Date Invalid"* when I'm trying to filter.
Here's the code:

```
 $this->setWidgets(array(
        'date' => new sfWidgetFormDateRange(
            array(
                'from_date' => new sfWidgetFormJQueryDate(array(
                        'config' => '{buttonText: "Choose Date"}',
                        'date_widget' => new sfWidgetFormDate(array('format' => '%year%-%month%-%day%'))
                    )
                ),
                'to_date' => new sfWidgetFormJQueryDate(array(
                        'config' => '{buttonText: "Choose Date"}',
                        'date_widget' => new sfWidgetFormDate(array('format' => '%year%-%month%-%day%'))
                    )
                ))),
    // ...
    $this->setValidators(array(
        'date' => new sfValidatorDateRange(
            array('required' => false,
                'from_date' => new sfValidatorDate(
                    array('required' => false)
                ),
                'to_date' => new sfValidatorDate(
                    array('required' => false)
                ))),
```

I am probably missing something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer, it's a bug in javascript of sfWidgetFormJQueryDate.

sfWidgetFormJQueryDate.class.php, line 106. Need to change

```
jQuery("#%s option").attr("disabled", '');
```

to

```
jQuery("#%s option").attr("disabled", false);
```

Because wrong code causes all options of *day* be disabled.

Comment: you're a life saver!! and the guys at sensio are lazy testers.. can't believe the don't have a testcase to submit a form!